# How to stop a object being created in a loop from begin destroyed in c++?

Tags: c++, object, memory, struct

I've defined a struct:

```
struct something {
    SimpleClass *object;
};
```

I want to create an array of these structs declared

```
something* array = (something*)malloc(sizeof(something) * 2);
```

I then loop through creating the struct, filling it with a object, and adding it to the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    something aSomething;
    SimpleClass anObject = SimpleClass(i);
    aSomething.object = &anObject;
    array[i] = aSomething;
    // Point 1
}
// Point 2
```

At some point the objects are destroyed because if I call this line (for example):

```
array[0].object->doSomething();
```

It runs fine at "Point 1", but I get an error at "Point 2".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In C++, you should be using `new`, not `malloc`.

Comment: Don't use malloc in c++

Comment: Do you *really* need `something` to hold a pointer to `SimpleClass`?

Comment: Y U NO use std::vector.

Comment: Yeah, scrap this whole thing for good and use std::vector<SimpleClass>. Ignore all the answers mentioning new.

Comment: Using new for the objects sorted it out. Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objects are being destroyed because they are local to the loop (created on the stack). Instead you have to use the keyword new for it to be created on the heap. Try doing this
`something & aSomething = *new something;

SimpleClass * anObject = new SimpleClass(i);

aSomething.object = anObject;

array[i] = aSomething;`
put this in the for loop instead of what you have
Also I would suggest using new instead of malloc to create your array since you are using c++

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful about the scope of your variables since you are relying on the stack.

```
SimpleClass anObject = SimpleClass(i);
```

This will be destroyed at the end of the loop. To keep something persistent you should allocate new memory for it with `new`.

```
SimpleClass* anObject = new SimpleClass(i);
aSomething.object = anObject;
array[i] = aSomething;
```

This should solve your problem. You also have to make sure you delete it later on, otherwise you will get a memory leak.

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
{
    delete array[i].object;
}
```

Note that in your example

```
something aSomething
```

will also get deleted at the end of the loop

Answer (score 1):

1) create objects using new operator instead of malloc

```
something* array = new something[2];
```

2) Since you are creating local object inside for loop after end of for loop the local objects "anObject " is getting destroyed. so you are seeing error outside for loop
Instead create a dynamic object to store.

```
 something*aSomething = new something();
 SimpleClass* anObject = new SimpleClass(i);
    aSomething->object = anObject;
    array[i] = aSomething;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use keyword 'new' to create both the array and its elements. Malloc is a C thing and obsolete in C++.